# How to add TabBar In Android

Tags: android

Respected All
             I have to add TabBar in my application, but i don't know how to add tab bar to application or activity. Can you help me for that.

Thank You
Vikram Kadam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `TabHost`.
You can find a clear example [here](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/02/07/using-android-tabhost/). Read the tuto for the explanations, here below you have just the code.
In short :
you need an xml file with some layout for each tab, and an activity to display the tabs :
In your xml tabs.xml :
     
    http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
    android:orientation=”vertical”
    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
    android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
    >

```
<TabHost
id=”@+id/tabs”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
>

<TabWidget
id=”@android:id/tabs”
android:layout_width=”wrap_content”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
/>
<FrameLayout
id=”@android:id/tabcontent”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”200px”
android:paddingTop=”30px”
>
<LinearLayout
id=”@+id/content1″
android:orientation=”vertical”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
android:background=”#ff99ccff”
>
<TextView
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:text=”tab item uno :) ”
/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
id=”@+id/content2″
android:orientation=”vertical”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
android:background=”#ffffcc99″
>
<TextView
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:text=”tab item dos :/”
/>
<Button
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:text=”tabhost needs”
/>
<Button
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:text=”to be upgraded ;) ”
/>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the `onCreate` method of your activity :

```
setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

TabHost tabs = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setup();

tabs.addTab(“one”, R.id.content1, “labelone”);
tabs.addTab(“two”, R.id.content2, “labeltwo”);
```

Thanks Jeff for the tuto

Comment: Sephy can we align that tab bar to bottom of screen.

Comment: Well, I don't know ... I'm used to using this with the default display. I think you need to override TabHost/TabWidget and change the bevahiour. That might be quite long...